# Are there ski exercises I can do whilst sitting at a desk?

Tags: skiing, training

I am office bound for 10 hours a day working at a computer. As I am off skiing this season, are there any exercises that will help my leg muscles I can do whilst sitting at my desk?

Comment: Check out the Fit Pack Chair Workout DVD by Joel Harper. It sounds kind of goofy, but is actually quite good: [http://www.joelharperfitness.com/shop/fitpack-chair-workout-dvd.html](http://www.joelharperfitness.com/shop/fitpack-chair-workout-dvd.html)

Answer (score 10):

Here are a few quick and easy ones that will help your **strength**:

- Squats will be the most useful. Not exactly at your desk, but you can definitely do it next to your desk.
- Seated leg raises. Keeping your legs straight, hold the side of the chair and raise and lower your legs
- Calf raises. Put your weight on your toes and lift yourself up. You don't need to raise far, just get your heels a couple of centimetres off the ground
- Standing up. Every opportunity you get, stand up. Simple, but useful
- Use the stairs. A lot. Don't go near the lift ever again

These will all help - but nothing office-based will really cover off the fitness requirements fully, especially **cardio** so I'd suggest using the gym, swimming or running as further exercise.

Comment: These are good for walkers too - you can also have a balled up coat or jumper between your knees, squeeze it together, then relax, and repeat.

Comment: @Rory: +1 for *Use the stairs. A lot. Don't go near the lift ever again*